# Design pattern and configuration settings

Tags: design-patterns, configuration

I'm developing an application that transforms xml documents using xslt.

The application has a settings dialog for setting values like

```
* input
* output (directory)
* stylesheet
* and so on...
```

The user can also choose to transform to pdf, xhtml, etc,  and the settings above differ slightly for each format. Now, I was wondering if anyone has any good ideas on how to handle these settings from a design perspective. I am sort of using an MVP (model-view-presenter) pattern for the application as a whole, and I have created a model class for these settings. Because they store the settings in different places and different ways (in build files for  transformations) I have subclassed the model class for each format type (PdfModel, etc). But besides having different ways of storing (which motivates subclassing), they also have different properties to some extent as I mentioned. For instance, the xhtml format needs a css property, and the pdf format needs a fo formatter property, and so on.

I have tried to work this out, and I get it to work fine in several different ways, so that's no problem. I'm just curious to know if anybody with good design pattern experience could shed some light on if this is really a good way to do it. It feels to me like a lot of it gets too complicated for a relatively simple thing. And yet it's hard to get a really elegant solution to it. For instance, if I do it as described above, I can use an interface to code to and that way I can have several different views (with presenters) showing the settings, not having to know what model will be presented (e.g. I have a property grid showing the current settings in a view besides the view where the user sets the settings). BUT the problem with this is that I then have to have an interface containing several properties that are not used for each format model. So for the pdf model, I will have to set the Css property to not applicable or something like that. And this could conceivably get worse, if I were to add more specific properties.

I also tried another variant where I only have the common properties in the interface, and then I code to the interface, but downcast the object in the receiving class to get to the subclass properties. I'm not sure if this is good or not, but it works. Maybe that's fine, but I would really like some input to find out if I'm overcomplicating things or I could do it more elegantly...

I hope it's possible to understand the problem from my description. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Anders

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted your current idea of what the properties interface would be, if you are looking for some best practice help.  That way those trying to answer could have some code to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should think in your design more about what is the common behaviour, not properties or methods by name.
It would be nice, if you could have a method providing all properties and associated constraints and validations. This method would be shared through the interface.
Another possibility could be for example some reflection functionality which could determine properties automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In the Head First OOA&D book they have an example with properties for an instrument, where they have a "spec" class embedded in the instrument class. The spec class has a sort of Dictionary that holds the properties that can vary between different instruments. Not a method, but is it sort of like that? I just sort of dislike that, because rather than being able to refer to a fixed property in another class I have to write strings for keys: Instrument.Properties("numOfStrings", 6). Could you provide simple examples?

Comment: I ment it just like that. I understand that you dislike the way you would have to work with those properties, to overcome that, a dynamic OOP language would be needed, which does that anyway, but with syntactic sugar and MethodMissing as common behaviour, when there is no property as specified.

Comment: Ok, not the answer I was hoping for, but maybe there is no better way, as you say. Either a dictionary, or accept having unused properties with a generic interface... Thanks for your input!

Comment: Back to your problem. Using statically typed language you don't have much choice. I tend to use enumerations instead of strings, they at least prevent misspelling. 
For more convenience, you could implement a Proxy, which will contain all possible methods and will delegate to those concrete models. This proxy will call work as you described(calling using strings), however you can work with it as usual and you can implement a common behaviour when called method(property) isn't found.

Comment: A follow-up: What about the views? Even if I could handle models using a dictionary instead of properties, the views will have a similar problem (a pdfview, xhtmlview and so on). These need to expose properties for the presenter to handle, right? But many are similar and could be put in a base view with an IView interface. But then if the presenters code to the IView interface they will again not have access to the properties in the subclassed views. To get rid of the unused properties in an interface the code gets so much more complicated, and I can't help feeling I'm missing something...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had thought of using enums to avoid misspelling, but I don't know the proxy pattern, so I might have to read up on that to see if it could help. That wouldn't solve the view problem I just asked about though, right?